# Servicestack cannot parse JSON array with leading whitespace

Tags: json, servicestack, servicestack-text

Using ServiceStack v4.5.6.0, JSON array cannot be parsed correctly when leading space exists.

```
var test1 = "[{}, {}]";
var test1Result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<JsonArrayObjects>(test1);
Assert.AreEqual(2, test1Result.Count, "this is ok");
var test2 = "  [{}, {}]";
var test2Result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<JsonArrayObjects>(test2);
Assert.AreEqual(2, test2result.Count, "this is not ok");
```

Is this the intended behavior of JSON arrays?
I believed that JSON parsing should ignore whitespace except for inside string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note this code wont compile as there's no `DeserializeFromJsonString` method.

But this [issue is now fixed](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/c51dcea3ac8f7f298272d02fb413dbdf5d5b1d04) and available from v4.5.7+ that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: thanks. edited question to fix the sample code error.